# mongodump no space on device error

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Ubuntu 14.04
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

doing backup of mongodb used for ceilometer in OpenStack Kilo. get no space error during back.  Where is partial back file? What file do I delete to get rid of the partial backup file. **How do I recover the space
taken up by the failed backup?**

```
stack@cloud:~$ mongodump --username ceilometer --password mypassword --host 3.2.0.10 --port 27017 --db ceilometer
...

Thu Apr 13 18:33:33.033         Collection File Writing Progress: 39821000/94803354 42% (objects)
Thu Apr 13 18:33:43.960         Collection File Writing Progress: 39824300/94803354 42% (objects)
Thu Apr 13 18:33:48.731         Collection File Writing Progress: 39827600/94803354 42% (objects)
**assertion: 14035 couldn't write to file: errno:28 **No space left on device****

stack@cloud:/$ df
Filesystem                 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                        49474116         4  49474112   1% /dev
tmpfs                        9897052      1552   9895500   1% /run
/dev/mapper/cloud--vg-root 381244660 361897752         0 100% /
none                               4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                            5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                        49485248         0  49485248   0% /run/shm
none                          102400         4    102396   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     240972    237343         0 100% /boot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify `--out` or `-o` on the command line to mongodump, the output would default to the current directory.

I would suggest you verify by running `ls -la ~/dump`. You can remove the dump by running `rm -rf ~/dump`.

Comment: Glad it worked @latenite4. If you wouldn't mind, please mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See:
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)